# Overriding Ember Controller 'needs' with Reopen

Tags: ember.js

I have a basic controller that I'd like to reopen so I can override the 'needs' parameter, but instead, the new parameter adds to the 'needs' parameter.

For example, my original controller looks something like this:

```
App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['blog', 'services', 'post_edit']  
});
```

I have a build process that includes this controller file in another app, and to avoid code redundancy, I'd like to be able to reopen the controller and make small changes to it as needed, including the 'needs' parameter. Like so:

```
App.MessagesController.reopen({
    needs: ['post', 'services']  
});
```

The problem is that when this code is run, the 'needs' parameter isn't overridden -- it's extended. It essentially becomes: `needs: ['blog', 'services', 'post_edit', 'post']`

Is there a way to override the 'needs' parameter of a controller with reopen? Or perhaps there is a better method altogether?

---

Edit for clarity:

Doing a lookup on the controller displays a console error that shows the 'needs' parameter is not being overridden.

```
$: App.__container__.lookup('controller:Messages');

Error: <App.MessagesController:ember322> needs [ controller:blog,    controller:post_edit ] but they could not be found
```

Adding another fake controller item to the 'needs' parameter in reopen adds to this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to extract the functionality that belongs in app 1 into a mixin, and include that on the controller.  Then share the base controller, with the shared functionality, across the two apps.

```
//Included in both apps
App.BaseMessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sharedValue:'foo'
});

//App 1
App.App1Mixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    needs: ['blog', 'services', 'post_edit']  
});

App.MessagesController = Ember.BaseMessagesController.extend(App.App1Mixin,{

});
```

Comment: This solution works great. Do you happen to know why reopen pushes to 'needs' rather than overriding it?

Comment: Yeah, reopen internally just passes in the properties as if they were a mixin, and applying a mixin merges the needs array (which is super useful when you have a slew of mixins with different needs).